# How to represent a many-to-many or many-to-one relationship in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning about MongoDB and I have a question: How do you represent Many-to-Many or Many-to-One relationships? In a standard SQL DB it would be simple:

```
Parent Table has fields ID (primary key) and Name.
Child Table has fields ID (primary key) and Name
Parent-Child-Relationship Table has fields ID (primary key), ParentID and ChildID

insert into table Parent (ID, Name) values (1, "Bob");
insert into table Child (ID, Name) values (1, "Mahmoud");
insert into table Parent-Child-Relationship (ID, ParentID, ChildID) values (1,1,1);
```

But I have not figured out how to do this in MongoDB. I could do:

```
db.parent.save({name: "Bob", children: ["Mahmoud"]});
```

But then how would I be able to create another Parent (Say "Mary") for Mahmoud??

Am I missing something obvious? Please help. I'm a complete newby to NoSQL technology.

Comment: In most cases you take the joins out of the database level and do them at the application layer. You can either embed the data on both parents or simply do two lookups. You can get a lot more info here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you don't.

The answer 10Gen would tell you is to use use a single document that is the parent, and subdocuments that represent the children.

However, don't do that, as subdocument queries in Mongo are limited and slower.

What everyone ends up doing is storing parent ID's on the children, and doing multiple queries/joins in the application level.

Comment: what makes you say subdocument queries are limited?

Comment: You cannot query more than one level deep in a sub document.

Comment: Also could you give me an example of not being able to query more than one level deep in a sub document?

Comment: For example:
`db.test.insert({'address': {'line1': {'street': 'Kanaha', 'number': '745'}}})`
then:
`test> db.test.find({'address.line1.street': 'Kanaha'}).count()
1`

Comment: maybe this was true at the time of writing, but seems they're pretty clear now on when to embed and when not to: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from creating another parent like below:

```
db.parent.save({name: "Jane", children: ["Mahmoud"]})
```

but I would say you are missing the point. Splitting data in row-like manner in document-oriented database is usually bad idea. Everything depends on application logic but if you want to reflect family data you can try for example structure like that:

```
db.family.insert({mother: {name: "Jane", age: 27}, father: {name: "Bob", age: 29}, children: [{name: "Mahmoud", age: 2}], })
```

Comment: Conceptually, this doesn't seem to work. What happens if we want to store relationships among the same objects Bob, Jane, Mahmoud and other different objects? What if we want to say Jane and Mahmoud were born in Chicago, but Bob was born in Tokyo? And what if each of those cities have a bunch of information associated with them respectively (for example population, long, lat, etc).

Has my mind just been straight-jacketted into always thinking about things in terms of tables and rows? Do I need to think about them differently?

Comment: IMHO pure relational model is much more universal that anything that document-oriented database can offer. Data modeling in document-oriented database like MongoDB is highly application dependent and like Jonathan Holland have written above large part of the job consist: "multiple queries/joins in the application level". One thing you should definitely avoid is data normalization. Generally you want to think more about hierarchical structure of your data instead of simple object - object relationships.